# Bootstrap show/hide li items based on li clicked in first dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show `li` items with a certain class in a second bootstrap dropdown based on the `li` item selected in the first dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('#mapContent').hide(); 
    $('#mapCat').click(function(){
        $("#mapContent").show();
        $("#mapContent ul li .show1").hide();
    });
})
```

The problem is the second ul is being show on click but all `<li>` items are being shown not just `<li>` with class of `'show1'` while on click only `<li class="show1"><a href="1">University X</a></li>` should hide in the second dropdown.

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/decker2/1dtkvqj8/5/)

Comment: Do you have a problem with this code?

Comment: sorry,  yes the second ul is being show on click but all <li> items are being shown not just <li> with class of 'show1'

Comment: so on click only   <li class="show1"><a href="1">University X</a></li> should hide in the second dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space `li .show1` which tells jquery to search for children of li but you want the li, remove it to get the li's

```
$("#mapContent ul li.show1").hide();
```

Comment: oh yeah! can I ask to hide <li> with more than one class?

Comment: yes you just put a coma and add your next class like `$("#mapContent ul li.show1,#mapContent ul li.show2").hide();`

Comment: will accept as answer once the 5 mins are up.  thanks again!